# Checkbox: uncheck when on another is checked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm trying to use this function to **uncheck** a checkbox when another one is **checked**:

```
<script>
   $('input.unchecked').on('change', function() {
   $('input.unchecked').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
   });
</script>

<script>
$("#checkboxID").change(function(){
$("#tableID tr.rowEG").toggle(!this.checked); 
});

$("#checkbox1OG").change(function(){
$("#tableID tr.row1OG").toggle(!this.checked); 
});

$("#checkbox2OG").change(function(){
$("#tableID tr.row2OG").toggle(!this.checked); 
});

$("#checkbox3OG").change(function(){
$("#tableID tr.row3OG").toggle(!this.checked); 
});   
</script>
```

But does not works, because when you check another checkbox the table content disappears.

This is the HTML code:

```
<form class="filter">
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxID" class="unchecked"> EG
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1OG" class="unchecked"> 1.OG
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2OG" class="unchecked"> 2.OG
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3OG" class="unchecked"> 3.OG
</form>
```

And here where I want to use it:

http://develop.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/table-test.html

Any ideas?

EDIT: 
Maybe this is the problem?

```
<script>
$("#checkboxID").change(function(){
$("#tableID tr.rowEG").toggle(!this.checked); 
});

    $("#checkbox1OG").change(function(){
$("#tableID tr.row1OG").toggle(!this.checked); 
});

    $("#checkbox2OG").change(function(){
$("#tableID tr.row2OG").toggle(!this.checked); 
});

    $("#checkbox3OG").change(function(){
$("#tableID tr.row3OG").toggle(!this.checked); 
});   
</script>
```

Comment: this code is working

Comment: That work for me http://jsfiddle.net/qYdwR/2603/

Comment: Your problem do not come from this code, can we have more ?

Comment: @SofieneDJEBALI i edited the first post with more script. The problem is that the check/uncheck works, but if you check my website i have different content fomr different checkbox.

Comment: Why don't you just use [radios](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/radio)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution without the need of script.

```css
input{
  display:none;
}

label{
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  font-size:16px;
  cursor:pointer;
  position:relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
} 
label ~ label {
  margin-left: 40px;
} 
label:before,
label:after{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position:absolute;
  height:15px;
  width:15px;
  content:' ';
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px #3a3a3a solid;  
  font-weight: bold;
}
input:checked + label:after{
  top: -2px;
  left: 2px;
  content: '\2713';
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<form class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio"><label for="radio"> EG </label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1"><label for="radio1"> 1.OG </label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2"><label for="radio2"> 2.OG </label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3"><label for="radio3"> 3.OG </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/61eywpzg/

**HTML**

```
<form class="filter">
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxID" class="unchecked"> EG
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1OG" class="unchecked"> 1.OG
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2OG" class="unchecked"> 2.OG
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3OG" class="unchecked"> 3.OG
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input.unchecked').on('change', function() {
    $('input.unchecked').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
});
```

Comment: I edited the first post with more script. The problem is that the check/uncheck works, but if you have a look to my website i have different content ffor different checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

**Try the below snippet:**

```js
$('.unchecked').click(function(){
  $(this).siblings().prop("checked",false)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="filter">
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxID" class="unchecked"> EG
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1OG" class="unchecked"> 1.OG
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2OG" class="unchecked"> 2.OG
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3OG" class="unchecked"> 3.OG
</form>
```

Comment: The check / uncheck works, but then i can't see the content of the div where i'm using the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use radio buttons instead of checkboxes.
To do this, change the type of your input to radio, example:

```
<input type="radio" id="checkboxID" class="unchecked">
```